# Missing all the options in the Send To menu

Tags: windows, windows-10, compression, zip, send-to

So I'm just trying to send a file to a compressed folder from Explorer. But for some reason the only option I have there is "Bluetooth device".

Did some Googling, found a suggestion to check the C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo folder to see if anything was missing. Everything is there as expected, but the option is missing when I right click. Shift+Right click doesn't help. I am not sure what else to do at this point.

Any ideas?

Comment: `reg query "HKCR\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\SendTo"` should return `(Default) REG_SZ {7BA4C740-9E81-11CF-99D3-00AA004AE837}`. Disable non-Microsoft context menu handlers one-by-one to find the culprit: try NirSoft's [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html)

Comment: It already does return that

Comment: Do you mean that you are "right-clicking on a file" and choosing right-click options, "Send to"? Also, what operation system are yo using? If Windows there are two ways that I may be able to help.

Comment: Something similar as to what JosefZ said. Copy this:      

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Send To]
@="{7BA4C740-9E81-11CF-99D3-00AA004AE837}"

  into notepad and do a save-as Sendto.REG on your desktop. Then after you save it, double click on it to run it. If you don't have suffixes visible you'll have to do the save-as with quotes to save the file with correct suffix in this manner; "Sendto.REG" in the naming bar when doing a save-as.

Comment: @ejbytes I did that, same result. To answer your earlier questions, it's Windows 10 & yes, I am right clicking on the file, pointing at Send To, and the only option in there is Bluetooth Device when normally it would say Desktop, Compressed File, etc...

Comment: One thing I learned to is as soon as your/my computer is in a good working condition, free of known bugs and malware etc, do a Full backup of the whole PC (especially operating system) and create a Restore Point. I know it's late for that right now, but have you tried to do a System Restore at an earlier date(hoping that you've done one)? A restore won't delete anything, it's aimed at the system.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on windows 11, when trying to tidy sendto, and add custom.

my user's original contents
[image]

One of the many glitches I've is that the extended context menu (shift+click) can be empty...

normal sendto
[image]

sendto with shift shows more including some stuff in %userprofile%
[image]

with shift when clicking and **continuing to hold shift when visiting sendto context menu option** the reported issue appears to be reproduced

[image]

Does the issue occur on all user accounts, including newly created ones?

Does the troubleshooter identify any issues? what about sfc?

It sounds like potentially user corruption, and the fix may be to create a new user.